# pygame module - window instantly is closing

Tags: python, pygame

I already checked other topics and I had tested these solutions and without any pos results.. I need to refresh topic with question. Where I have an error?

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 1000, 800
window = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))

def run(window, width, height):
    run = True
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    fps = 60

    while run:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                break

        clock.tick(fps)
    
        pygame.quit()

if __name__ == "_main_":
    run(window, WIDTH, HEIGHT)
```

Comment: Your function and your `run` boolean have the same name, this could be causing some clashing. I'd recommend changing one of those names.

Comment: chanded, but the sproblem still persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change from single underscore to double underscores around `main` here:

```py
if __name__ == "_main_":
```

It should be

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

Comment: you are right,now I ocur next issue with error message from VCS: for event in pygame.event.get():
pygame.error: video system not initialized

Answer (score 0):

The quit invocation should not be on the while block but after it. Otherwise it quits immediately.
Therefore:

```
def run(window, width, height):
    run = True
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    fps = 60

    while run:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                break

        clock.tick(fps)
    
    pygame.quit()
```

Comment: tried your solution but window still disappear.

Answer (score 0):

It is a matter of [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). The window is closing because you are calling `pygame.quit()` in the application loop. You need to call `pygame.quit()` after the application loop.
The name of the [top level code environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html#module-__main__) is `"__main__"`, but not `"_main_"`:

```py
def run(window, width, height):
    run = True
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    fps = 60

    while run:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False

        clock.tick(fps)
    
    # INDETATION
    #<--|
    pygame.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":           # <-- 
    run(window, WIDTH, HEIGHT)
```